# jquery tooltip not working - items and content specified

Tags: javascript, jquery

The amount of time I have been spending on this is crazy. I have an element on the page with the id invited-count. This is definitely getting called after the element is in the dom. Can someone put me out of my misery?

```
$("#invited-count").tooltip({
    items: "#invited-count",
    content: "Hello World",
    track: true
}).tooltip("open");
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is this using jQuery UI or some other library or what? Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: Silly question, but is it a z-index issue? Where are you loading the tooltip in your DOM. Check and make sure it is not firing, and just hiding behind something by giving the tool-tip div a high z-index.

If you are positioning the invited-count div absolutely, then it has to be z-indexed relative to the lowest absolutely positioned element in the parent/child stack.

Comment: @thomas This is using JQuery UI. It works when using fiddle...

Comment: Worked for me too. I think he has a z-indexing problem, and since we dont know how his page is structured there is no way to verify. pQuestions123, could you please create a fiddle so we can see the structure of your page?

Comment: ya works for me http://jsbin.com/tuqelakevi/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

add to your div a title attribute `<div id="invited-count" title="Hello World">Ok bb</div>` and with js just do this `$("#invited-count").tooltip();` 
working here :

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  
</head>
<body> 
 <div id="invited-count" title="Hello World">Hello Tooltip</div>
</body>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#invited-count" ).tooltip({track: true});
  });
  </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so thanks John for you answer. I wasn't able to use it exactly because I need to set the tooltip content dynamically. That said I used a very similar approach:

```
$("#invited-count").attr("title", firstRowData.TOOLTIP_INVITED).tooltip();
```

and what is funny is that the following statement:

```
$("#invited-count").attr("title", firstRowData.TOOLTIP_INVITED).tooltip({
                        items: "#invited-count", content: "Hello World", track: true
                    });
```

produces a tooltip with the value of `firstRowData.TOOLTIP_INVITED` not `"Hello World"`...